# Overlay an app on top of another

Tags: windows-store-apps

Any way I can write a windows store app (for phone or other) which will allow me to draw on top of other apps? In other words, I'd like my app to run in the background and not handle any user gestures but be able to draw on a semi-transparent overlay / canvas above any other running apps. I can do this in windows 7 but WinRT is new to me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible due to the sandboxed nature of Windows Store Apps to do something like this (much akin to iOS). Windows 8 has much tighter security in its applications, so much so that you can't even take a screenshot in a metro app, because if a user has split the screen to hold two apps, you could potentially capture information from the other application.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I've encountered this problem before and have found no viable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts kirinthos, I was wondering perhaps if I could go the C++/DirectX route and get access to the graphics device.